# Java Out of Memory Error while using Stanford POS Tagger

Tags: java, python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am getting the following error in my Jupyter notebook:

```
Loading default properties from tagger C:\Users\bdiplus_admin\Desktop\ABSA\stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger
Loading POS tagger from C:\Users\bdiplus_admin\Desktop\ABSA\stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger ... done [1.5 sec].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:37)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.runTagInference(TestSentence.java:341)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.testTagInference(TestSentence.java:328)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.tagSentence(TestSentence.java:151)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagSentence(MaxentTagger.java:1052)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagCoreLabelsOrHasWords(MaxentTagger.java:1843)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagAndOutputSentence(MaxentTagger.java:1853)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1764)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1825)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1598)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTagger(MaxentTagger.java:1554)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1897)
```

It basically says that I am out of memory.

I've looked up the error and the most common solution I have got is to try to specify the maximum memory with `-Xmx4096M`. However, **my issue is that I don't know where to put this argument?**

I using the following lines of code in a Jupyter notebook that's running on Python 3:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger as POS_Tag
from nltk import word_tokenize

_path_to_model = home + '/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger' 
_path_to_jar = home + '/stanford-postagger.jar'
stanford_tag = POS_Tag(model_filename=_path_to_model, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)

def posTag(review):
    tagged_text_list=[]
    for text in review:
        tagged_text_list.append(stanford_tag.tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    return tagged_text_list
```

Comment: It looks like it's a command line argument... Maybe try running it with subprocess from python?

Comment: @Novak Hey! Thanks, but I don't know anything about subprocesses. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Check it out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). It's basically an interface through which you can execute your command in the system terminal. So it enables you, for example, to run the POS tagger through Command Line Interface (CLI) as you would in the terminal and capture the results in python. It's actually a fairly common way to run other programs and scripts that are not written in python.